# Printing a list of class objects, need to erase space on end of last object?

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to print a list of class objects like so:

```
for order in location_orders:
    if (len(location_orders) >= 2):
        print("{0}\n".format(order)) 
    else:
        print(order)
print("-" * 24)
```

So basically it's printing out the class objects fine, but I had to add a "\n" to separate them when there are more than one in the list. The problem is this will print a "\n" after the very last object, where I need it to be flush so I can print something else there. Is there a way I can erase the previous empty line only if it exist with the

```
print("-" * 24)
```

print statement?
Or alternatively, is there a way I can just separate the orders with a new line?
I can't index into them because they are class objects, therefore I can't use the sep=" " function.

Answer (score 0):

This will print them w/ a space separator:

```
print " ".join( location_orders )
```

If you require each to be formatted, then

```
print " ".join(["{0}".format(order) for order in location_orders])
```

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I want them separated by a line, not a space. But I guess I would just go use "\n".join and it would work

Answer (score 0):

There's no general way to undo a line that's been printed. Once a line is sent to the terminal, you can only back up to rewrite it using (very involved) platform specific libraries like `curses`.

But you don't really need that. Since your list is iterable, you can unpack the whole thing into a single `print` call using the `*args` syntax. Then you can use the `sep` argument to put the double newlines in between them:

```
print(*location_orders, sep='\n\n')
```

The class instances will be formatted with `str`, just like they are when you format them one by one (unless you've written an unusual `__format__` method for the class).

Another reasonable way to do it (which unlike argument unpacking would also work with Python 2 `print` statements) would be to use `str.join` to join individual strings (that you create from each instance in a generator expression) into a single string that you print in the end:

```
print('\n\n'.join(str(order) for order in location_orders))
```

Since we're turning the instances into strings more explicitly here, we could use `format` instead of `str` if it really made a difference (usually a `format` call with no special formatting code should be the same as `str`).